# Moderate user uploaded images

Tags: media, files

I want offer a solution that a registered user can upload Images through File entity but like Copyright, Privacy and laws i want to check the image before the Image will be public.

The best solution would be if the not checked image would be temporary in a folder. If the Image is ok then i want to select it and change it to other other folder which has public access. (i can play here with CHMOD permissions on Linux). If the image isn't ok it should be deleted and not reachable via public access.

The background is, if a image including copyright infringement or other criminal materials then it should't be public reachable. It means if i hidden or don't make it with Views public in Frontend available a visitor can with right URL open the image.

I use the modules:

- File Entity (last dev)
- Views 3
- Panels 3
- VBO Views Bulk operations

Has anyone an idea? Maybe with Rules module?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [File admin](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_admin) module.

> File admin extends the File entity module to add administrative
>   options to files, including published, promoted, and sticky status.

If you decide to use the module please also look at the issue queue. Although the module is stable a few extras can be had by applying a few select patches, especially [Create tie in for views_bulk_operations](https://www.drupal.org/node/1869106) as you are using that module.